# Add special characters to a String property through a PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I'm displaying the properties of a class in a `PropertyGrid`. The class has a property `RegEx`, which not surprisingly is  a regular expression as a string.

However, I am not able to type something like `[0-9]{6}` into the `PropertyGrid`. The field in the property grid only seems  to accept letters, numbers, and basic punctuation.

How can get the property to accept characters like $, {, }, #, @    . ..etc..etc?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use string.
like

```
Regex regex = new Regex("w+$");
```

Comment: I don't think you understand. I can create a Regex through a string just fine. It editing a string through a property grid with special characters like those listed in the original question that I'm having trouble with.